# site - mandatory redirection

Tags: iis, redirect, dns

My company was divided in two divisions so the sites which were running like http://app.mycompany.com

now they should run as, 
http://app.mycompany-divisionone.com

How I should proceed to redirect the requests to the right web address, because many users have his bookmarks using the old domain.

Also there are bookmarks like http://app.mycompany.com/myform.asp

All this is running into a intranet so I could change IIS, DNS, etc..

Using IIS 6 and Windows 2003.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a page on this - 
[Redirecting Web Sites in IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true)

Hope it helps.